# Device ID Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

we had set up a app in mobile push, however, when a new applier install the app, the contact shows in all contact including wrong device ID which it's actually contains in system token.

Not sure how can we adjust the code.

We had follow the instruction from mobile push document.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Specifically, what code have you implemented and what is it doing that you do not expect?  Device IDs are generated during the initial SDK initialization and will never be duplicated.  System Tokens (aka Push Tokens or Device Tokens) are similarly generated by Apple/Google and will never be duplicated.  If, however, you have violated the uniqueness requirement of http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html#contact-key then you could be assigning all devices to the last registered device/contact.

Comment: Hello Bill, we are following this page (http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html) . When sending from Marketing cloud, it says send, but non of the applier received the message. However, when we send the push from app side, we did received. Actually, the device ID that issued by Marketing Cloud shall not goes wrong. But we are not sure why can't the push be received.

Comment: Please open a support case through your account manager.

Answer (score 0):

@victoria, are you using the MobilePush SDK? If so, what platform & version are you implementing?

The deviceId value is automatically generated as a unique identifier by the SDK and sent to the server for association with the contact. It is an internal value.

A system token is generated and passed by your application code to the SDK.

Does your application call our setContactKey() method? Is that using a unique value per device/user?

If necessary, I suggest you open a support case with your Marketing Cloud rep so that we @murilo, in addition to gathering the information Seth has requested, please be sure to log a support request with your Marketing Cloud representative.

We will be much better able to track, respond and be held accountable to you (and all our customers) needs via customer support.

Of course, continue to raise questions and concerns here - the MobilePush SDK team is happy to help in any way we can.

Comment: Hello Brian, 

yes, we are using Mobile Push SDK(Android SDK6.1.0)
I had attached the SDK link here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_lOr2aOADtqFWNB4EhvnIdk4fgZiRJFx?usp=sharing
Plus, we are facing the contactkey are not mapping the the contact as well...

We did log a case already that still get no clue, that's why I'm trying to ask for help here :(

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please open a support case through your account manager.